# Prevent React-native WebView from downloading a PDF

Tags: android, react-native, google-chrome, webview, android-webview

This question is relevant to all Android Chrome browsers I think, but in my case I am using the React-native WebView (which is compiling to the native webview in the app). I should add that this works fine on iOS because a URL which points to a PDF just loads that PDF in the browser.

So, I'm wondering whether there's a way to force the Chrome browser to load a PDF in the browser using a header?

Or, is there a URL that allows you to pass the PDF url in as a param? Some kind of proxy service.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  The device chrome browser or the react native webview (which uses the chrome browser).    Are you trying to trap a link in a webpage and open the device browser?

Comment: Viewing the PDF instead of the webview attempting to download it as a file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this issue by using Google Docs to display the given pdf url. Just replace `my_pdf_url` with your pdf url.

https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=my_pdf_url